# Dynamic Array in Excel vba that saves errors made in Data entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a code for data validation. The excel colors the cells that are entered incorrectly (orange for wrong range, red for wrong datatype). I first used message boxes to show the wrong values but when I have a lot of entries it is annoying to all click all of them away. My new idea would be to save all the errors as Strings in a dynamic array, which i can print out in a loop at the end and show all at once. Unfortunately, I am a beginner in vba and dont know if this idea is even possible to execute. How could I implement this idea?

```
Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim DblLengthMin As Double
'Dim dynamicArray() As String
'Dim f As Integer
DblLengthMax = 20000
DblLengthMin = 5

lCol = Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
lRow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

For Each rng In Range("C2", Cells(lRow, lCol))
    If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
      rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     'Array Entry: "A number has to be entered " & "Row " & rng.Row & " Column " & 
     'rng.Column
    End If

   If IsNumeric(rng) And rng.Value > DblLengthMax Or rng.Value < DblLengthMin Then
     rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
     'ArrayEntry "Value in " & "Row " & rng.Row & " Column " & rng.Column & " is out of 
      'range. Check for unit (mm)"
    
  End If

Next rng

' Print out an extra window that shows the number of mistakes made and a list of them 
 and their place in their worksheet   

End Sub
```

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI1yz.png)

Comment: Look up examples to dynamically adding values to an array then customize based on your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684942/appending-a-dynamic-array-in-vba

Comment: Where are you planning on displaying this information?  In a messagebox, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a Report For Cells Not Matching Criteria

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub CheckColumns()

    ' Define constants.

    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfCol As Long = 3
    
    Dim dHeaders() As Variant: dHeaders = VBA.Array( _
        "Id", "Mistake", "Value", "Row", "Column", "Action Needed")
    
    Const gteMin As Double = 2
    Const lteMax As Double = 20000
    Const rColor As Long = 26367 ' a kind of orange
    Const cColor As Long = 255 ' red
    
    ' Write the source data to a 2D one-based array ('sData').
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim srOffset As Long: srOffset = 1
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count - srOffset
    Dim scOffset As Long: scOffset = sfCol - 1
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count - scOffset
    
    Dim sdrg As Range
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srCount, scCount).Offset(1, sfCol - 1)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sdrg.Value
    
    ' Write the report data to 1D one-based arrays ('dDataRow')
    ' of a collection ('coll') and combine the cells containinig mistakes
    ' into ranges ('rrg','nrg').
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(dHeaders) + 1
    Dim dDataRow() As Variant: ReDim dDataRow(1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Dim rrg As Range ' not in range
    Dim nrg As Range ' not a number
    
    Dim sItem As Variant
    Dim sRow As Long
    Dim sCol As Long
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim sc As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim IsNumber As Boolean
    Dim InRange As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            sItem = sData(sr, sc)
            If VarType(sItem) = vbDouble Then
                IsNumber = True
                If sItem >= gteMin Then
                    If sItem <= lteMax Then
                        InRange = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If InRange Then
                InRange = False
                IsNumber = False
            Else
                dr = dr + 1
                dDataRow(1) = dr
                dDataRow(3) = sItem
                sRow = sr + srOffset
                dDataRow(4) = sRow
                sCol = sc + scOffset
                dDataRow(5) = sCol
                If IsNumber Then
                    dDataRow(2) = "Not in range"
                    dDataRow(6) = "Check for unit (mm)"
                    Set rrg = RefCombinedRange(rrg, sws.Cells(sRow, sCol))
                    IsNumber = False
                Else
                    dDataRow(2) = "Not a number"
                    dDataRow(6) = "Enter a number"
                    Set nrg = RefCombinedRange(nrg, sws.Cells(sRow, sCol))
                End If
                coll.Add dDataRow
             End If
        Next sc
    Next sr
    
    If coll.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No mistakes found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Highlight cells.
    
    srg.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not rrg Is Nothing Then rrg.Interior.Color = rColor ' not in range
    If Not nrg Is Nothing Then nrg.Interior.Color = cColor ' not a number
        
    ' Write the report data from the arrays in the collection
    ' to a 2D one-based array, the destination array ('dData').
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dr + 1 ' include headers
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dc As Long
    
    ' Write headers.
    For dc = 1 To dcCount
        dData(1, dc) = dHeaders(dc - 1)
    Next dc
     
    ' Write data
    dr = 1 ' skip headers
    For Each sItem In coll
        dr = dr + 1
        For dc = 1 To dcCount
            dData(dr, dc) = sItem(dc)
        Next dc
    Next sItem

    ' Write the data from the destination array to a new single-worksheet
    ' workbook, the destination workbook ('dwb').

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    With dwb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(, dcCount)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        .Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
        
    dwb.Saved = True ' just for easy closing
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Columns checked.", vbInformation

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend you to save all cells addresses with errors in one string variable with separator, and what is wrong in the other string variable. For example:

```
Dim strErrorAdress as String
Dim strError as String
For Each rng In Range("C2", Cells(lRow, lCol))
    If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
      rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      If strErrorAdress = "" Then 
      strErrorAdress = rng.address & "/" 
      strError = "A number has to be entered" & "/"
     Else
      strErrorAdress =strErrorAdress & "/" & rng.address & "/" 
      strError = strError & "/" & "A number has to be entered" & "/"
     End if 
    End If

   If IsNumeric(rng) And rng.Value > DblLengthMax Or rng.Value < DblLengthMin Then
     rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
     If strErrorAdress = "" Then 
      strErrorAdress = rng.address & "/" 
      strError = "A number has to be entered" & "/"
     Else
      strErrorAdress =strErrorAdress & "/" & rng.address & "/" 
      strError = strError & "/" & "range. Check for unit (mm)" & "/"
     End if 
    
  End If

Next rng

'Afterr all code delete last "/" in strings with 
  strErrorAdress = Left(strErrorAdress , Len(strErrorAdress ) - 1)
    strError = Left(strError , Len(strError ) - 1)
'Then make arrays with split function
Dim arrSplitstrError() As String
Dim arrSplitstrErrorAdress() As String

arrSplitstrError = Split(strError , "/") 
arrSplitstrErrorAdress = Split(strErrorAdress , "/") 

'Now print errors like 
dim counter as long
For counter = 0 to UBound(arrSplitstrError)
debug.print arrSplitstrErrorAdress(counter) & " - " & arrSplitstrError(counter) & vbNewLine 
next counter
```

I'm not an expert, maybe there is a mistake in the code but the idea should be understood.