# Sorting cells by colour and putting their address into an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, preserve

I want to put the values from cells with background colour that are different from -4142, in an array so that later I can insert those values in a dropdown list.

I found code in the answer of this question:
[Appending a dynamic array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684942/appending-a-dynamic-array-in-vba).

I get

```vb
error 13 incompatible types
```

in the line `myArray(X) = cell.Address`

I don't know if the message is that in English because my VBA is in another language, but the error number is 13.

```vb
Sub SelectByColor()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim myArray() As Double, X As Long
X = 0
'For understanding LR = Last Row
LR = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

ReDim Preserve myArray(X)
Set rng = Range("B2:B" & LR)
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
        myArray(X) = cell.Address
        X = X + 1
        If X < N Then ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To X)
        mystr = mystr & cell.Address & ","
    End If
Next cell
mystr = Left(mystr, Len(mystr) - 1)
MsgBox mystr
MsgBox myArray(X)

End Sub
```

`mystr` is to see if the code would be getting the correct values, and it is, but it is not appending in the array.

Comment: `Cell.Address` is a String (eg $A$1), your array contains Numbers (Double). What exactly do you want to collect in those array? The color would be `Cell.Interior.Color`

Comment: I have to create a dropdown list containing the values/string of the cells that have the different backgorund color. So I thought that I would be able to create that dropdown list with the array containing the address of those cells. Is that wrong? Because the range for the dropdow list is not nice and beautiful such as A1:A10, is not continuous, such as A1 then A3 then A101 and so on, and I have to put these valeus/Strings in the dropdown list.

Comment: Where do you use the dropdown list: within a userform or as data validation list?

Comment: As a data validation list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** You get your runtime error because you declares your array to hold numbers, but you are trying to write addresses (=strings) into it. An cell address (eg $A$1) cannot be converted into a number and therefore VBA throws that error 13.

**(b)** A list of values used as Data Validation can be created by a range of cells or by a (hardcoded) list of values. However, the range need to be contiguous, which is not the case for your requirements.

So what you need is a list of *values*. The values need to be separated by ",". You can do the by creating an array as you do in your code and then use the `Join`-function. However, the array needs to be of type String or Variant, it will not work with Double.

As I don't like to use `Redim Preserve` in a Loop (very inefficient), I changed the logic by sizing the array with the maximum of possible values (LR) and then use only a single Redim to remove unused entries after the values are filled.

```
ReDim myArray(LR)
Dim X As Long, rng as Range, cell as Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & LR)
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 and not isError(cell.value) Then
        myArray(X) = cell.Value
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next cell
Redim Preserve myArray(X)    ' Remove unused entries
```

Set the validiation:

```
 With Selection.Validation  ' <-- Replace Selection with the Range where you want to apply the validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(myArray, ",")
 End With
```